# Is it possible to have multiple Oracle application instances on the one host and port and database via jdbc?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, port, host

On Sybase and SQL Server, in general you partition application instances by host and port and database. (So you have multiple database application instances on the one server but different ports, and vice versa).

So you connect in jdbc with something like this:

```
"jdbc:mssql://hostname:port/dbname"
```

So this would be two databases running on the one instance:

```
"jdbc:mssql://myhost1:1234/db1"
"jdbc:mssql://myhost1:1234/db2"
```

And this would be two application instances running on the one host:

```
"jdbc:mssql://myhost1:1234/db1"
"jdbc:mssql://myhost1:1235/db1"
```

And this would be two application instances running on two different hosts:

```
"jdbc:mssql://myhost1:1234/db1"
"jdbc:mssql://myhost2:1234/db1"
```

I saw today what appeared to be multiple Oracle application instances on the one port and host, differentiated by a description field in the JDBC string. It looked like this:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)
(PORT = 1234))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = 
DEV1)))

"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host1)
(PORT = 1234))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = 
DEV2)))
```

Am I mistaken or **is it possible to have multiple Oracle application instances on the one host and port via jdbc?**

Assumptions:

- I'm distinguishing between *database* being the schema partition in the application and the *application instance* being the program running on the server.

Comment: yes why not, whats the issue in that

Comment: Thanks - have clarified the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, using jdbc or sql*net, you connect from a client to a database using host, port and service_name. That service name points to a database. There can be mulitple databases running on a host, there can also be 1 database running that hosts several services, or a combination of the two.

We prefer to create consolidated databases where multiple applications are hosted in a single database where each application has it's own service_name. Resource manager is used to manage the load and to protect applications against a rogue app that tries to get all systems resources.

So, the short answer is: yes.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer. I've realised the question wasn't very clear. Hopefully it is clearer now.

Comment: answer remains the same. Distinguish between ORACLE_SID, which is very physically tied to a database and SERVICE_NAME, which gives a lot of freedom. Prefer not to use a default service_name.

Comment: So you're saying the service name is the jdbc database name?

Comment: Yes, in the jdbc url you can configure ORACLE_SID or SERVICE_NAME. The preferred form is using the service_name since this gives the ability to connect to the same database using different service_names, that allows for more control of resources.